# How can I keep a folder backed up online with continuous syncing?

Tags: sync, backup

I've found that the dropbox support for Titanium Backup never works for me amd I've also tried using ubuntuone and idrivesync but neither of these support setting a directory to keep in sync.

Does anyone know of a free service, that can keep any directory of your choice backed up online?

The best would be a scheduled task so that the battery isn't drained by continuous sync.

Comment: By "titanium" do you mean [Titanium Media Sync](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.MediaSync)? (That's the accepted solution for this related question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/complete-dropbox-implementation-for-android )

Comment: Actually I didn't know about titanium media, I've edited the question to be more specific about titanium backup. Seen as it's from the same people, I'm not too confident in the dropbox support working for me, much as I love their backup solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DropSync](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync). It can sync any specified folder and you can setup a schedule. Recent update of free version of the app removed limitation for the schedule.

Comment: This appears to be the solution! Currently syncing thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Didn't [dropbox](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dropbox.android) native client worked for you?

Comment: The dropbox client doesn't appear to work for me unfortunately. I can browse files remotely and open them but I can't keep a whole directory of choice in sync automatically.