# Is there an app or method that will let me use a cloud-synced folder on the SD card?

Tags: sync, dropbox, cloud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Complete dropbox implementation for Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/complete-dropbox-implementation-for-android)

In my case I have a bunch of roms and save files I want to keep in sync across devices, the desktop dropbox app lets me store these files in a "real" folder in windows so any application can access them normally, but once they're changed on my pc/server they get updated. Is there any app that lets me do something similar on android? The cloud apps I've looked at so far (dropbox, box.net, boxroid) only allow for downloading single files at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SugarSync](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.sharpcast.sugarsync&feature=search_result) does this. They specifically market it as a way to keep your photos backed up, but it works for any file/folder. They describe their "Autosync" system in [this blog post.](https://www.sugarsync.com/blog/2011/04/25/new-android-app-reinvents-mobile-photo-backup/)