# Dropbox export folder to SD card?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-ace, file-transfer, files, dropbox

Is it possible to download a folder (or at least download multiple files at once) from Dropbox to SD card?

I do not seem to have the export option when selecting folders

[image]

Note the "Share" option doesn't have save to SD either.

Comment: I think this is unfortunately still not possible with the Dropbox app (discussed back in January here: [Can I download whole folders in Dropbox app?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17920)

Comment: I use DropSync to keep a folder on my SD card synced with my Dropbox (it works more or less like the desktop app). The DropBox mobile app is more of a mobile app version of the web site, rather than a real sync tool.

Comment: @MichaelKohne I don't really need to sync my SD to Dropbox. I just need to download a folder from Dropbox to SD.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5lc3Ryb25ncy5hbmRyb2lkLnBvcCJd) has support for several cloud storage providers. It allows to "copy" folders from your dropbox folder to your SD-Card etc in a similar fashion as you would copy files locally. The "Network" Tab allows you to add an account.

[image: Adding the dropbox account]
[image: Allows to copy folders from your dropbox directly to your sd-card]

Comment: Nice! I had ES Explorer installed but I didn't know about this feature. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the folder synced with ES?

Answer (score 1):

[Astro File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro&hl=en) (like ES File Explorer) also has support for dropbox and allows you to download folders.

For a dedicated app, there is [Folder Downloader for Dropbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jjinx.dropboxdownloader) which works just with your dropbox account.

Answer (score 0):

(I don't use the Dropbox app on Android; does it not keep local copies?)

[DropSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd) keeps specified Android folders synced with specified Dropbox folders. No need to export; it's (almost) always there. 'Almost' as in: the changes I make on Android get uploaded right away; changes made to Dropbox files by some other device get downloaded at the next scheduled (or manually initiated) sync. The only time I ever need to think about it is when I have two devices open and I'm working with both of them.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [Total Commander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander&hl=en) for Android and its [totalbox plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sk.onkokubo.tc.dropbox&hl=en) for Dropbox files manipulation tasks. It's almost as convenient as on a PC.