# Sync music folders between phone and tablet

Tags: wi-fi, sync, file-transfer

I want to use a DJ returnable app on both devices, send want a fast way (WiFi) to keep the music folders sync'd. I always buy from my phone so just need to transfer existing music and new downloads from the phone to the tablet, it doesn't need to sync automatically but I do need a way to do easy multiple/bulk file transfers.

What is a good way to do this? Wifi preferably but bluetooth if I have to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Complete Dropbox implementation for Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/complete-dropbox-implementation-for-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DoubleTwist](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doubleTwist.androidPlayer&hl=en) with [AirSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doubleTwist.androidPlayerProKey&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLmRvdWJsZVR3aXN0LmFuZHJvaWRQbGF5ZXJQcm9LZXkiXQ..) will do this, as long as they're connected to the same WiFi network and looking at the same location.

For bulk file transfers, most file explorers (like [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en)) allow you to browse devices from other devices on the same network.