# How to sync folders via cloud in a Dropbox-like way

Tags: file-transfer, cloud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Complete Dropbox implementation for Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/complete-dropbox-implementation-for-android)

How can I sync as much as possible of the folder-structure of my phone to the cloud, and from there to the desktop in a DropBox-like way?

Typical applications could be to move photos off the phone (Move it out on my desktop and have it reflected on the phone), and to put podcasts on the phone.

If I could put Dropbox to sync the root of the SD card or perhaps the whole file-system it would it principle do it ( Most of these kind of apps use a dedicated folder, which is not logically on the SD card).

I have seen one pay add-on to DropBox that seems to do this.
(I prefer free of course)

One issue is that i already use DropBox for other purposes, so it would be better to use the free quota of another provider.

Comment: This answer might be what you're looking for: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/23258/13391 You'd need the paid version though.

Comment: Dropsync up in the same thread looks more promising (Than FolderSync that you refer to).

Comment: I have only used Foldersync from the recommended apps. But you also asked for something that syncs with something other than DB and foldersync can do that. Dropsync can't.