# How to keep files downloaded via Dropbox after uninstalling app

Tags: sd-card, dropbox

I want to know whether there is any app on the Google Play Store which

- stores all dropbox files to memory card whenever there is net
  available
- Leaves the files in my memory card even after I uninstall the app

Comment: App recommendations are off topic here sorry!

Comment: its ok.I got it @LiamW

Comment: @Sampath: What Liam is trying to say is, rather than asking us to help you find your already-identified solution (an app), you should ask about the problem you're trying to solve. Keeping the files downloaded via Dropbox after removing the app seems like a decent question to me. The solution may very well be an app, but not necessarily. Please review the [FAQ].

Comment: See also: http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/1289/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-a-product

Comment: Further, the first part of your question would seem to be covered here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/complete-dropbox-implementation-for-android

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by

clicking on the arrow on the extreme right of the items you want to save

cick export and save it to a selected place on your sdcard

Answer (score 0):

For the 2nd point, you can copy or move the downloaded Dropbox files in another folder before uninstalling the application. Take your favorite file manager and do it.